# Why bitcoins not reflected in bitcoin wallet after being transferred from Web based wallet to its address even after ten confirmation?

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-wallet-app

[[image]]

[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZusWB.png)I have purchased bitcoins worth  12$ using localbitcoins.com and send it to my wallet address(bitcoin developers).  In blockchain.info it is showing it has ten confirmations yet it is not being reflected in my wallet? I have updated the wallet. Its been six hours.

My wallet and my blockchain.info information  is shown

Please help me.

Comment: https://blockchain.info/address/1Q7D2ECCYBxJY6z29RG8HqhaLQzN7E29Rf  you can see its confirm by fifteen or more people yet it's not showing in my wallet  what can I do about it???

Comment: this looks like an issue to your wallet software. The display from your wallet doesn't match the info you show from blockchain.info. So you need to find out, what are the keys stored in your wallet (eventually call support team), and go from there. I cn't even see which type of wallet you have, the blockchain.info wallets have a blue interface...Is it localbitcoins? Then you might ask the team there.

Answer (score 1):

The address shown in Bitcoin Wallet App is a different one than the recipient address shown on the blockchain.info screenshot. Unless you created a second address with Bitcoin Wallet App, that would explain why Bitcoin Wallet App doesn't show the above payment—it went somewhere else.